# Webpack and PostCSS seperate setup

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, postcss

I want to check CSS changes without Webpack, with separate command, so React and Typescript run with Webpack and CSS with Post CSS.

Problem is that when I run postcss command it does what is supposed to, but Webpack returns the error. It can't resolve @import without the loader.

I know how to setup webpack and CSS but want do it this way.

Here are the commands and configs:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
"css:watch": "postcss --watch ./src/css/main.css -o ./dist/main.css"
```

PostCSS config:

```
module.exports = {
    parser: 'postcss',
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
}
```

Webpack config:

```
var path = require('path'),
    htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader'
            },
            // {
            //     test: /\.css$/,
            //     use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
            // }

        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ],
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    mode: 'development'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  {
test: /\.css$/,
use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
  }
```

instead of

```
// {
            //     test: /\.css$/,
            //     use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
            // }
```

Comment: It works with Webpack, I want to run it seperately, Webpack and PostCSS